# OpenCL Compute units and GPU Processing units mismatch

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I'm a bit confused about compute units. I have an nvidia gtx 1650Ti graphics card. When I asked for max_compute_units, it returns 16 units, and max_work_group_size is 1024.
But when I executed the kernel:

```
int i = get_global_id (0);
result [i] = get_local_id (0);
```

I get the repeating local id range from 0 to 255. How does this relate to the max_compute_units returned by the graphics card? Is this an error in max_compute_units value and the gpu actually has more compute units than it indicates? Or does OpenCl get_local_id have its own distribution logic not tied to hardware? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL compute units refer to streaming multiprocessors (SMs) on Nvidia GPUs or compute units (CUs) on AMD GPUs. Each SM contains 128 CUDA cores (Pascal and earlier) or 64 CUDA cores (Turing/Volta). For AMD, each CU contains 64 streaming multiprocessors. This refers to the hardware. The more SMs/CUs, the faster the GPU (within the same microarchitecture).

The work group size / local ID refer to how you group threads in software into so-called thread blocks. Thread blocks are useful for matrix multiplications for example, because within a thread block, communication between threads is possible via shared memory. Thread blocks can have different size (sort of an optimization parameter, either 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 or 1024 (`max_work_group_size`)). Based on your GPU, some intermediate values might also work. On the hardware (at least for Nvidia), the thread blocks are executed as so-called warps (groups of 32 threads) on the SMs. For Turing, one SM can compute 2 warps simultaneously. If you choose the thread block size 16, then each warp only computes 16 threads and the other 16 are idle, so you only get half the performance.

In your example with the local ID (this is the index in the thread block) betwqeen 0 and 255, your thread block size is 256. You define the thread block size in the kernel call as the "local range". `max_work_group_size` does not correlate with `max_compute_units` in any way; both are hardware / driver limitations.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! As far as I understand, my gpu is capable of simultaneously processing 16 workgroups (max_compute_units) and each group can support up to 1024 threads in total in 3 dimensions (max_work_group_size). Now everything has become much clearer! So I should try to use all available threads for each workgroup (`local range=max_work_group_size`), and reduce the total number of workgroups for maximum performance, right?

Comment: Although everything seems to be a more complicated. A balance is supposedly needed between the number of workgroups and the number of threads within the group. Since the most important factor is memory access, which is much longer than the calculations. It is necessary to maintain such a ratio of workgroups and their threads so that the first processed group receives a response from memory, while the last in the queue is being processed. As I understand this approach is called Latency hiding. Please correct me if I'm wrong. But how to find the right ratio? Is there some formula for this? Thx!

Comment: Whether memory access really is the bottleneck depends on your exact algorithm. For the 1650 Ti, if your algorithm performs less than 16 floating-point operations per byte that is transferred from/to memory, then memory bandwidth is the bottleneck, otherwise compute performance. See roofline model on Wikipedia. Latency hiding is less influenced by the choice of work group size, but more by your memory access pattern (Structure of Arrays vs. Array of Structures). You should choose AoS to get memory coalescence, only then you get peak memory bandwidth and latency is hidden.

Comment: Large workgroup size is not always beneficial. In large work groups you can better use shared memory, but if there is if-else branching and some of the threads have the if-branch and some the else-branch, all threads within the workgroup have to execute both branches and discard the results of the other branch. If workgroups are smaller, then it is more likely that within a workgroup only one branch is executed by all threads (then the other branch does not have to be computed at all) and you get better performance. Try different sizes and see which has best performance in your application.